# Convert string into type of the string's value

Tags: go

I want to dynamically create type instances based on string values. For example, given the following:

```
type MyType struct {}

var input = "MyType"

var result = GetType(input)
```

I want `reflect.TypeOf(result) == MyType` to be true.

The best I can come up with is using a `map[string]MyInterface{}` as a lookup for each type that meets `MyInterface` but this is less dynamic that I would like, as it requires me to update the table with each new type I create. Is there any logic inside of `GetType(string)` I could use which would do this more dynamically?

Comment: The "lookup" approach, that you've outlined, is the usual approach in Go. There's no function in `reflect` that will load all the types from the ether (or runtime) and make them available to you. You yourself must first register the types before you can create them from the ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Go, types are statically defined at compile time, and you cannot create or change types dynamically based on string values at runtime. Therefore, it's not possible to directly achieve what you're asking for using the built-in type system.

Comment: Makes sense, was hoping there was some arcane Go-Fu that could help me out here but I guess I'm butting up against a core design principle of the language itself. Oh well, lookup map it is then.

Answer (score -3):

```
package main

 import (
     "fmt"
     "reflect"
 )

 type MyType struct{}

 func GetType(input string) interface{} {
    // Get the type by name using reflection
    typ := reflect.TypeOf((*MyType)(nil)).Elem()

    // Create an instance of the type
    instance := reflect.New(typ).Elem()

    // Return the created instance as an interface{}
    return instance.Interface()
 }

    func main() {
     input := "MyType"
     result := GetType(input)

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(result) == reflect.TypeOf(MyType{})) // true
   }


    enter code here
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).